# Regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I know it's a simple problem but i'm blocked on it : i want to retrieve all strings written in this form :

```
$F{ETIQX}
```

Where X is a number. i wrote this regular expression but i'm getting errors :

```
 if (textField.getText().matches("$F{ETIQ\d}")){
  System.out.println("matches!!");
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to retrieve all strings

Then you shouldn't be using `.matches()` in the first place. but a `Matcher` and `.find()`. `.matches()` is a misnomer. It will succeed only if the *whole* input matches the regex (in contradiction with the definiton of regex matching which can occur anywhere in the input).

Also, your regex should be:

```
"\\$F\\{ETIQ\\d\\}"
```

(you need to escape backslashes in a Java string)

`$`, `{` and `}` are regex metacharacters; the first is an anchor matching the end of input, the two latter are bounds for a repetition quantifier.

Your code should read:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$F\\{ETIQ\\d\\}");

// ...

final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(textField.getText());

while (m.find())
    // work with m.group()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\$F\{ETIQ\d\}
```

escape character which have meaning in regex.

```
$ means end of string
{ means start of a quantifier
} means end of a quantifier
```

for matching these you must escape them to match them literally.

here is a demo http://regex101.com/r/xT4mR6

In java `\` has no meaning and will throuw an error , so we need to escape `\` with `\`.

Comment: So you should also escape the last bracket

Comment: @AndiKrusch Yes we should escape the last bracket also, i missed it